# Running a file as nonroot from a root bash script

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

Okay, I currently use an eggdrop IRC bot on my server. I want to make a bash script to start it up as well as a few other scripts at the same time. All that's left is to make it start, but it won't run as root.

However, I also need to be in the current directory of the file to run it, or it displays an error.

For example:
/home/eggdrop/eggdropbot/eggdrop will display an error, so to run it I need to
cd /home/eggdrop/eggdropbot and then ./eggdrop

So I can't just use "sudo -u eggdrop /home/eggdrop/eggdropbot/eggdrop" and as you probably know, sudo won't cd, either, since that would be pointless.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just `cd` first and then `sudo -u ./eggdrop .`?

Comment: Because somehow I'm an idiot and didn't think of that. One second let me try it.

Comment: Ugh I'm an idiot, worked like a charm. I actually thought of that earlier and I guess I forgot about it. Was trying too hard to make it a bit more simple, I guess. Only managed to make it more difficult. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What about doing the `cd`, and, only then, launch the command with `sudo` ?

I suppose something like this should do the trick :

```
cd /home/eggdrop/eggdropbot && sudo -u eggdrop ./eggdrop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `cd` to the directory as the root user and then use `sudo -u` to invoke the program from the working directory.